# When would \DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given} and \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} give different results?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, author

My `foo.bib` is like this:

```
@book{tgt,
  title = {The Great Title},
  author = {Jane Doe and Ron Wonder},
  year = {2022},
  publisher = {Macmillan},
  address = {Paris},
}
```

My LaTeX code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}
\begin{document}

A proof can be found at \textcite{tgt}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output I get:

> A proof can be found at Doe and Wonder (2022).
>
> #### References
>
> Doe, Jane and Wonder, Ron (2022). *The Great Title.* Paris: Macmillan.

But if I change my LaTeX code to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}
\begin{document}

A proof can be found at \textcite{tgt}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I still get the exact same output.

What is the difference between `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}` and `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`? Under what circumstance do these two ways of sorting first name, last name give different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `author` is not the only name that can appear at the head of an entry. If you cite an entire `@collection` (e.g. `gaonkar` in `biblatex-example.bib`), the `editor` will appear in the `author` position. In certain situations you can even have a `translator` there.

`sortname` applies to `author`, `editor` and `translator` in the "primary name" position. `author` only applies to author. For consistency I'd always use `sortname`.

Compare the effects in

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,vizedom:related,gaonkar,westfahl:frontier,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

Note that some styles don't define `sortname`, so there you might have to say

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}
```

first to see any effect.

Comment: Got two questions. 1) Thank you so much for a detailed answer. I generated two outputs with your code example. With `sortname` first: [sortname.png](https://i.imgur.com/OUHMl1d.png). And again with `author`: [author.png](https://i.imgur.com/ZNJvQnI.png). The only difference I see between the two is how the name "Caffee, Gabrielle L." is sorted. In the first one it has `family-given` but in the second it has `given-family`. Why is only "Caffee, Gabrielle L." affected? Is it because this name occurs in `translator` field (not `author` field)?

Comment: 2) I see that the difference between `sortname` and `author` is reproducible with a shorter `\autocite` like `Lorem \autocite{vizedom:related}`. Is there a reason why you chose a long `\autocite` like you did in your post? What are `gaonkar:in` and other citations relevant in your example? (Sorry, I am still new to this stuff and trying to wrap my head around all of this. Thank you for your help!)

Comment: @LoneLearner Oops wrong `gaonkar` reference. It should have been `gaonkar` not `gaonkar:in`. Though to be fair you can't really see a lot because `sortname` is `family-given/given-family` by default, so a difference to `family-given` only comes in for the second name. Try `given-family` instead of `family-given` to see a real difference. (Or make up your own `@collection` entry with several `editor`s.)